# How to capture image from video when right button of mouse is clicked in open cv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I an working with open cv , I am facing problem in capturing image from video.
My basic need is that when video is running in open cv ,as soon as I click  right button of mouse program should capture the image from video then image should be saved at any location. After that on saved image I have to perform further image processing.
Please any one help me.

Comment: OpenCV supports mouse callback. For the video, it is read frame by frame, therefore, create a global variable that stores the current frame and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. You need mouse callback, write an image, and running a clip, therefore this is my code for your question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>



cv::Mat currentFrame;

 static void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int, void* )
 {
    static int count(0);
    if ( event == cv::EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN ) {

      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << count;
      std::string countStr = ss.str();
      std::string imageName = "image_" + countStr;
      std::string FullPath = "/home/xxxx/" + imageName + ".jpg";
      cv::imwrite( FullPath, currentFrame );
      std::cout << " image has been saved " << std::endl;
      ++count;
   }
 }

int main()
{

    std::string clipFullPath = "/home/xxxx/drop.avi";
    cv::VideoCapture clip(clipFullPath);      

    if ( !clip.isOpened() ){
        std::cout  << "Error: Could not open the  video: " << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }


    cv::namedWindow("Display", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::setMouseCallback("Display", onMouse, 0 );

    for(;;){

       clip >> currentFrame;  

        if ( currentFrame.empty() ) 
              break;        

        cv::imshow("Display", currentFrame);
        cv::waitKey(30);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

you need `-std=c++11` for `std::to_string()`. If you want to save an image through GUI window, I think you need another library such as Qt that supports this functionality.

$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

Edited: the OP needs capturing frames from webcam rather than a video.

This is the code for your question in the comment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"


cv::Mat frame;

 static void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int, void* )
 {
    static int count(0);
    if ( event == cv::EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN ) {

      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << count;
      std::string countStr = ss.str();
      std::string imageName = "image_" + countStr;
      std::string FullPath = imageName + ".jpg"; // save to the current directory
      cv::imwrite( FullPath, frame );
      std::cout << " image has been saved " << std::endl;
      ++count;
   }
}


int main()
{
    // access the default webcam 
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0); 

    // Double check the webcam before start reading. 
    if ( !cap.isOpened() ){ 
        std::cerr  << "Cannot open the webcam " << std::endl;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cv::namedWindow("webcam",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::setMouseCallback("webcam", onMouse, 0 );

    while ( true ){

       // acquire frame 
       cap >> frame;

       // Safety checking 
       if ( !frame.data ){ 
         std::cerr << "Cannot acquire frame from the webcam " << std::endl;
            break;
       }

       cv::imshow("webcam", frame); 

       if ( cv::waitKey(30) == 27){
        std::cout << "esc key is pressed" << std::endl;
        break; 
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The images are saved in the directory of the executable file. In the terminal command (i.e. I'm using Mac and OpenCV 2.4.11 )

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lopencv_highgui.2.4.11 -lopencv_core.2.4.11
```

Comment: This code is giving error as. to_string ,Error more than one instance of overloaded function "to string" matches the argument list: @CroCo

Comment: how should I get std=c++11 for std::to_string @CroCo

Comment: @ShaikIbrahim, which operating system you are using? In Linux, `g++ -std=c++11 `

Comment: Provide more info regarding your code (OS, compiler, ... etc)

Comment: ,I am using raspberry pi which contain rasbian wheezy OS. And i m using g++ compiler for compiling the code. rasbian wheezy is debian linux.

Comment: Does the compiler support c++11 features? if not, just replace the function with another function that converts `int` to `string`

Comment: no it doesn't support c++11 feature. It is request to you that how c++11 feature can be added in my OS

Comment: ,g++ (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1) 4.6.3 , it is showing like this for g++ compiler

Comment: I've modified the code so that you don't need `std::to_string()`

Comment: ,now it is showing error like this, terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error what() : basic_string:: _S_construct null not valid aborted

Comment: sir it is working properly , but it is taking video from the drive but i want to take video from the web camera.  when i am changing like this std::string clipFullPath(0);
cv::VideoCapture clip(clipFullPath); it is showing above error. plz help me

Comment: You said in your question `capture the image from video` not from a webcam. You need to be more clear.

Comment: sorry for this inconvenience sir. I am facing lots of problem with my project work. I need image capturing from web camera If right button is clicked. Then the captured image should be saved in the drive , then the from the save image from drive i want to read that image using cv:: imread function after this i want to do image processing on this image.

Comment: I've included the code for capturing from  webcam. If this answers your question, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: you can easily avoid the string issues by using `cv::format("/some/path/%d.png", number);`